# Laravel Spark referToTeamAs method is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

In my `SparkServiceProvider.php` where you set up your spark configuration and plans, I have `Spark::referToTeamAs('group');`

When I visit `/missing-group` I'm getting a 404 error because var_dumping $teamString in `/spark/src/Http/routes.php` is showing `team` and not `group`. So it looks like my setting is not catching before that routes file is used.

Is there any way to set the teamString before that routes file is called? Like changing the order of the service providers or something?

I'm not really sure where to start. Thanks in advance!

**App\Providers\SparkServiceProvider**

```
...

/**
 * Finish configuring Spark for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function booted()
{
    Spark::collectsBillingAddress();
    Spark::afterLoginRedirectTo('/dashboard');
    Spark::referToTeamAs('group');        

    Spark::useStripe()
        ->noProrate()
        ->noAdditionalTeams();

    Spark::plan('Individual', 'stripe-individual-ticket')
        ->price(300)
        ->features(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
        ->yearly();

    Spark::teamPlan('Group', 'stripe-group-ticket')
        ->price(300)
        ->features(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
        ->yearly();
}

...
```

Comment: Can you post that portion of your `SparkServiceProvider.php`?

Comment: @Samsquanch I've added the relevant portion of the SparkServiceProvider

Comment: From the docs -- `Be sure to call this method in the register method of your service provider, as Spark will not function correctly if it is called in the booted method. Additionally, make sure you pass the singular, lowercase form of the word.`

Comment: That worked! Submit it as an answer and I'll give you credit for the answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/4.0/teams):

> Be sure to call this method in the **register method** of your service
>   provider, as Spark will not function correctly if it is called in the
>   booted method. Additionally, make sure you pass the singular,
>   lowercase form of the word.

So instead of

```
public function booted()
{
    ...
    Spark::referToTeamAs('group');
    ...
```

You'll want

```
public function register()
{
    ...
    Spark::referToTeamAs('group');
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spark version 6+ `referToTeamAs` is now `prefixTeamsAs`

Answer (score 0):

Adding another provider that runs the `boot()` method before Spark defines the routes works:

**App\Providers\ConfigureSparkServiceProvider**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Laravel\Spark\Spark;
use Laravel\Spark\Providers\SparkServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class ConfigureSparkServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Spark::referToTeamAs('group');

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And then remember to add it to the list of providers in `/config/app.php` and it works!